# Apple Receipt Validation 21002 From Ruby on Rails with Typhoeus Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, verification, receipt, typhoeus

I have some rails code which get's an in-app purchase receipt from Apple and verifies it towards either sandbox or production. This has worked fine, but as of lately I am seeing some 21002 (The data in the receipt-data property was malformed) errors in my logs. I can see these are from apps in production.

Below is my RoR code that verifies the receipt, do you see anything that would cause a 21002?

Thanks so much!

```ruby
def verifyReceipt (receipt_data)

# Checking the magazine status to get the proper verification url 
if Publication.find_by_app_id(params[:app_id]).development_mode
    logger.info "Sandbox mode detected"
    url = "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"
else
    logger.info "Production mode detected"
    url = "https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"
end

# Get the magazines shared secret
shared_secret = Publication.where("app_id = ?", params[:app_id]).first.itunes_shared_secret

if shared_secret.nil? or shared_secret.blank?
    # Invalid magazine
    logger.info "Shared secret does not exist or does not match iTunes shared secret!"
    result = false
else
    logger.info "Verifying receipt from Apple now!"
    # Verify receipt with apple based on magazine status, and save results
    data = { "receipt-data" => receipt_data, "password" => shared_secret }
    request = Typhoeus::Request.new(url, method: :post, body: data.to_json )
    request.run
    result = JSON.parse(request.response.body).with_indifferent_access
    logger.info "Result from verification: #{result[:status]}"
end
return result
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is on production, it is a normal behavior to get 21002 errors some times.

The major cause is someone use JB device or IAP cracker on your native app and try to do a fake purchase. The fake receipt failed in the AppStore validation and a 21002 error is returned.

You may do a formal purchase to make sure everything works well in case.

Comment: Aha I didn't know that! Thanks a lot for sharing. I know purchases are going through, so it sounds like exactly what you are describing. Thanks!

Comment: How can you know if the receipt is an actual hack attempt or the 21002 "The data in the receipt-data property was malformed or missing" error is because there's an actual problem on the data? Could it be some kind of charset conversion? some weird character? Or do we have to rely on Apple non-very descriptive error codes?

Comment: To do the validation, you need to send the receipt data to the AppStore. This receipt is encoded in base64 and comes from the native app directly when doing a purchase. You don't have to do other processes on the receipt and so there is no such "conversion" problem as well. The only thing need to do is to ensure the receipt is sent correctly.